# Circular loop in java.util.LinkedList

Tags: java, linked-list

Is it possible for a `java.util.LinkedList` to be circular?

If so, how could that be detected?

Apparently java's `LinkedList` is implemented as a real linked list, although it uses a private `Node` class that is not accessible to perform such a check.

Comment: A Java `LinkedList` can't be circular, please clarify your question.

Comment: A lot cleaner and less rambling

Comment: You can look at the source code for [java.util.LinkedList](http://developer.classpath.org/doc/java/util/LinkedList-source.html)  to understand that there is no such operation supported by `java.util.LinkedList` that can lead to create a cycle in a LinkedList.

Comment: Sounds good. It's clear now. No need to use Node class for this class, then.

Answer (score 0):

A Java LinkedList cannot have cycles because the user doesn't have access to create the and link nodes.